# Vertx services not accepting messages continuously when running on local JVM over a finite set of data when deployed as separate fat-jars

Tags: java, vert.x

I am getting started with vertx and was trying out point to point messaging on event bus. I have 2 services both created as separate maven projects and deployed as fat-jars

1) Read from a file and send the content as a message over an address - ContentParserService.java

2) Read the message and reply to the incoming message- PingService.java

Both these services are deployed as separate jars kind of a microservice fashion

The code is as follows: ContentParserService.java

```
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        super.start(startFuture);

    // Reference to the eventbus running on JVM
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

    // Read file using normal java mechanism
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(
                (config().getString("filename")))));

        bufferedReader.readLine(); //read first line

        String line = null;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(",");

            // Create RealEstate Object
            RealEstateTransaction realEstateData = createTransactionObject(data);

            // Construct Message JSON
            JsonObject messageJSON = constructMessageJson(realEstateData);

            // Send message to PING address over the Event Bus
            eventBus.send("PING", Json.encode(messageJSON), reply -> {
                if (reply.succeeded())
                    System.out.println("Received Reply: " + reply.result().body());
                else {
                    System.out.println("No reply");
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        startFuture.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The code is as follows: PingService.java

```
 @Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
    super.start(startFuture);

    System.out.println("Referencing event bus");
    // Reference to the event bus running on the JVM
    EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();

    System.out.println("Creating HttpServer");
    // Create HTTP Server to handle incoming requests
    HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

    System.out.println("Creating Router");
    // Create Router for routing to appropriate endpoint
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    System.out.println("Starting to consume message sent over event bus");
    // Consume the incoming message over the address PING
    eventBus.consumer("PING", event -> {
        System.out.println("Received message: " + event.body());
        event.reply("Received at PING address");

    });
    System.out.println("Receiver ready and receiving messages");
```

When i run both the services I run on the same machine with the java -jar command for each of the service. What i observed was when i deploy the first jar of ContentParserService, it immediately starts and sends messages over the event bus, but by the time i start the pingservice jar , it is not able to receive any message sent over the event bus because my pingService is a separate fatjar and a microservice in itself. The file that i am reading is a finite lenght csv file of around 200 entries. This case would work if i bundle both the services in a single fat jar.

How should i achieve the different fat jars services able to send message to each other in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case works when both verticles in the same jar only because there's no network delay. But your usecase for EventBus is incorrect, since it doesn't persist messages, hence cannot replay them. You should start sending messages only when the other side is ready to receive them.
You need to reverse the dependency. In your `ContentParserService` register for some "ready" event, then start your `while` loop only when you get it:

```
vertx.eventBus().consumer("ready", (message) -> {
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
   ...
   }
});
```

Now, what will happen if `ContentParserService` is actually slower and misses the "ready" event? Use `vertx.setPeriodic()` for that. So you start your `PingService`, and periodically tell `ContentParserService` that you're ready to receive some messages.

Or, as an option, just don't use EventBus at all between you services, and switch to something with persistence, like RabbitMQ or Kafka.

Comment: Understood. Persistence of messages if required, then event bus is not a solution.However, as per your solution, if i send periodically, wont the contentParserservice keep processing messages and read the whole file again and again?So how about going through each line , but anyways, its better to go with persistant messaging layer for the same.

Comment: You would have to unsubscribe from the "ready" event first time you receive it. But anyway, EventBus is more of a nice mechanism to communicate between actors, not between microservices, as in your case.